# AngularJS service's POST to web api controller results in Object properties being null

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to form an object and post it to the web api controller. The action looks like this:

```
        public HttpResponseMessage Post(Contacts contact)
        {
            db.Add(contact);
            db.SaveChanges();

            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            return response;
        }
```

AngularJS controller posts like this:

```
        $scope.submitData = function submitData() {
            console.log($scope.contact);
            $http.post('api/Contacts', $scope.contact);
        }
```

The problem is that the data which needs to be posted has properties which are shown as Object in the console (Addresses in this example).

[image]

After the post all the Addresses count is null on the web api controller side, but not the other plain properties have the corresponding value.

[image]

How can I pass the Objects to be readable on the web api side?

Contacts model:

```
public partial class Contacts
    {
        public Contacts()
        {
            this.Addresses = new HashSet<Addresses>();
            this.Emails = new HashSet<Emails>();
            this.PhoneNumbers = new HashSet<PhoneNumbers>();
            this.Tags = new HashSet<Tags>();
        }

        public int ContactID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Addresses> Addresses { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Emails> Emails { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PhoneNumbers> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Tags> Tags { get; set; }
    }
```

How i fill the addresses object:

```
            <fieldset class="container" ng-repeat="i in getAddress() track by $index">
                <legend>Address {{$index + 1}}</legend>
                <label>Street:</label>
                <input ng-model="contact.Addresses[$index].Street" class=" form-control" type="text" /><br />
                <label>Number:</label>
                <input ng-model="contact.Addresses[$index].Number" class="form-control" type="text" /><br />
                <label>City:</label>
                <input ng-model="contact.Addresses[$index].City" class="form-control" type="text" /><br />
                <label>Country:</label>
                <input ng-model="contact.Addresses[$index].Country" class="form-control" type="text" /><br />
            </fieldset>
```

Comment: Can you show us your Contacts definition?

Comment: given that this class is partial, can you share the full code, the other part of this class